# FrozenDate::parseDate doesn't work with September

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

Is there a reason why `FrozenDate::parseDate`, called with the month of September (ex. Sep), the date doesn't get parsed?

Code:

```
$months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

foreach($months as $m)
{
    $d = "01-".$m."-23";
    debug($d);
    $fd = FrozenDate::parseDate($d, "dd-MMM-yy");
    debug($fd);
}


APP/Controller\AdministratorsController.php (line 202)
'01-Sep-23'
APP/Controller\AdministratorsController.php (line 204)
null
```

**Edit #1**

Tried outputting any errors using `getLastErrors()`. Nothing there either.

```
debug(FrozenDate::getLastErrors());

APP/Controller\AdministratorsController.php (line 205)
[
'warning_count' => (int) 0,
'warnings' => [ ],
'error_count' => (int) 0,
'errors' => [ ],
]
```

**Edit #2**

Seems using "Sept" works. Noting that I'm importing from Excel and the format given is "Sep" and not "Sept". And, the date "01-Sept-23" converts to "01-Sep-2023" in Excel for some reason.

```
$months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

foreach($months as $m)
{
    $d = "01-".$m."-23";
    debug($d);
    $fd = FrozenDate::parseDate($d, "dd-MMM-yy");
    debug($fd);
}
```

**Solution**

Set a locale prior to calling the `parseDate()` function.

```
FrozenDate::setDefaultLocale("en_US");//en_CA doesn't work
```

Comment: Is there anyway you can show us a reproducible example? `Sep` looks fine for `MMM` as mentioned [`here`](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/)

Comment: @nice_dev the code above should replicate nicely, minus the debug lines that I also included. Noting that I just discovered that "Sept" works.

Comment: The above code doesn't. [`FrozenDate`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.3.16/src/I18n/FrozenDate.php#L28) requires us to install many dependencies it seems and that would be tedious for us. _Importing from Excel_ is anew information we didn't know beforehand.  [`The date field symbol table`](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/format_parse/datetime/#date-field-symbol-table) seems to give `September` for `MMMM` and assuming the converse would be true as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLDR/ICU problem, in newer versions (not sure about the latest, can't test it right now), for certain locales either `Sept` was introduced, or `Sep` was removed, or vice versa, or some combination or whatever. It's not clear to me from any of the comments, and I really don't feel like wasting hours to investigate it.

tl;dr, classic CLDR/ICU L. Better get used to it, stuff like this happens regularly.

- **https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/browse/CLDR-15317**
- **https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/browse/CLDR-14678**

Comment: Wow. Ok, will try to deal with it as best as I can. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, setting the locale to en_US seems to work.